# Is there a way to set attributes for child windows in Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

**Topic: Electron Touch Application**

*FULL SCREEN PRESENTATION FOR EKIOSK*

I have now developed a touch application based on HTML and CSS, which I can open as an app based on the Electron Quick-Start.
The app opens in fullscreen and without frame.

Now I have the following situation: In my app there are also external websites included, which I integrate via IFrame in an area of the touch presentation. On one of these external websites there are links that have "_blank" set as target attribute. As soon as I click on such a link, a 2nd window opens, as usual. My only problem is that the 2nd window also opens fullscreen and without frame. So it is not possible to close the window without keyboard.
It would be better for me if other windows would not open fullscreen because of the "_blank" attribute, but in another format and maybe even with frame.

LONG STORY SHORT:
Is it possible to specify that windows that are NOT the main window open in different proportions?

Code of my main.js:

```html
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')



function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false,
    fullscreen: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      devTools: false
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('src/index.html')
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I developed a solution from different approaches in GitHub and Stackoverflow. It was not easy, but in the end I was able to find a solution.

For those of you who came here with a similar problem, here is my solution:

```
  win.webContents.on('new-window', function(e, url) {
    // make sure local urls stay in electron perimeter
    if('file://' === url.substr(0, 'file://'.length)) {
      return;
    }
  
    // and open every other protocols on the browser      
    e.preventDefault();
    //shell.openExternal(url)
    let win2 = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1366, 
      height: 768,
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      parent: win
    })
    
    win2.loadURL(url);
  })
```